# Redirect to a page passing parameters (without change the url)

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

In Controller I've this

```
public static Result index(String message, String alert) {
    return ok(index.render(message, alert));
}
```

Route file

```
GET     /        controllers.Application.index(msg: String, alert: String)
```

Then, in other method I've these return:

```
return redirect(routes.Application.index("String message 1", "String message 2"));

return ok(index.render("String message 1", "String message 2"));
```

What I want to do is redirect to index page passing two strings to display in index.scala.html :

```
@(message: String, alert: String)

@main("Ready") {
    @if(message) { 
        <div class="alert">
          @Html(message)
          @Html(alert)
        </div>
    }
}
```

Both the return don't work. I get this error from Eclipse:

```
The method index() in the type ReverseApplication is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)
```

and this from play compilation:

```
render(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) in views.html.index cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)
```

**EDIT**:

with `render` it's ok but: it render the index page but the url remains the old one. Is it correct?

with `redirect`: it redirect the page but it appends to the url the passed strings

```
http://localhost/?message=Stringmessage1&alert=Stringmessage2
```

What I want is a redirect to a page passing strings, but with the url of the redirect. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You messed things a little:

```
// This is a redirect to an action (public static Result index()) which in your case hasn't these 2 String args declared in route/method definition
return redirect(routes.Application.index("String message 1", "String message 2"));

// This one renders the view `index.scala.html`
return ok(index.render("String message 1", "String message 2"));
```

TIP: Just rename your index view file to ie. `indexView.scala.html` and then use like:

`return ok(indexView.render("String message 1", "String message 2"));`

to avoid mistakes.

And just confirm: you **can** use arguments in your redirections, anyway remember that they need to be declared in routes file and are **NOT** optional in java actions.

Comment: Thanks for clarify, could you check the updated code and the Edit in first post?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way I've tried to do what I need:

controller

```
public static Result save() {
  flash("success", "The item has been created");
  return redirect(routes.Application.index());
}
```

index.scala.html

```
  @if(flash.contains("success")) {
    <div class="alert">
      @flash().get("success")
    </div>
  }
```

With the use of `flash` I can "pass" a string to the redirected page without change the url.